# UITableview not scrolling smoothly when load image in cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CountryCell *a_cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CountryCell" owner:self options:nil]firstObject];
    NSDictionary *countryInfo = [arrCountryCode objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    a_cell.lblName.text = [countryInfo valueForKey:@"name"];
    a_cell.lblCode.text = [countryInfo valueForKey:@"dial_code"];
    a_cell.imgCountry.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[countryInfo valueForKey:@"code"]];
    a_cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return a_cell;
}
```

I use JSON file, In that country mobile code, country name and  flag image name that add in project.

e.g

```
{
     "name":"India",
     "dial_code":"+91",
     "code":"IN"
}
```

using this code loading data for all country list with it's flag images. When i scrolling this tableview it's not scrolling smoothly. Please help me for soothly scrolling tableview with image.

Comment: I think the problem maybe because images has a much bigger size than `UIImageView` size. You can try to resize current images and make them have almost same size with size of `UIImageView`. It will reduce time `UIImageView` used to resize image before displaying. Beside of it, you should use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` instead of initializing a new cell from bundle.

Comment: trungduc Thank you for you suggestion. It's working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Using `NSData` in `UIImage` means taking time . Try this one to directly From `URL` to `UIImage`

```
[imageviewname setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someurl.com/path/to/image.jpg"]placeholderImage:placeholoderImage];
```

i hope u have  AFNetworking  in your project. if not means this code will shown error

Comment: Yes i have AFNetworking  in my project. I have all image in Assets , i am not loading images using URL. so suggest me for that.

Comment: are you reload again and again or using `UIBezierpath` in uitableview cell

Answer (score 0):

First

`IN` is not image name that you have for variable code...

Second

`UIImage imageNamed` is used to load images that are added in the app & not online images

---

If you want to load images from online, better use library named [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

Below is how you will call

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

....

[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourweb.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

That's it...